# swap space allocation vs swaptotal

Tags: swap, virtual-memory

I created a Red Hat 9 virtual machine on VMware Workstion 9 by allocated the physical memory of 256MB. See pic.

[image: physical memory]

When installing Linux, I created the swap partition with a size of 256MB. See picture.

[image: Add Partition]

And got the partitioning like below.

[image: Partitioning list]

But after the installation completed, I checked through the command

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

I got the result

```
SwapTotal:     1052248 kB
SwapFree:      1047956 kB
```

I got a screenshot

[image]

Which is very confusing. Is the size of the swap space decided by the "Add Partition" during OS installation process?

Comment: What?  "Installation designation"?  The size is however big you made it.  What does `cat /proc/swaps` and `fdisk -lu` say?

Comment: Evidently you created a 1GB swap area. Maybe the installer considers 256MB too small and increased the value? It would have told you so.

Comment: @psusi will give accurate return value on Monday when I will get access to the vm in my company computer.

Comment: What does `swapon -s` say? `fdisk -l`? (Why RH9?)

Comment: One possible reason about the discrepancy might be a swap file is being used.

Comment: My memory on this is foggy at this point, it's been ~10+ years since using RH9, but I seem to recall that it would always create a 1G swap partition, by default, and I don't believe the UI would allow you to change it. You had to go in after and resize the partition if you wanted a smaller one.